# Python comparing a date with different ranges of dates in one go

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare a date with different sets of dates in one go. Looks like my present code compares each date with three lists and producing three  results. With this approach, each day resulted in three different results. Instead, I want each date to be comapred to three date ranges in one go and produce the result.
My present code is

```
exp1= [dates_bwn_twodates('2019-03-22','2019-04-09'),onemod,'exp1']
exp2 = [dates_bwn_twodates('4/10/2019','4/29/2019'),sixmod,'exp2']
exp3 = [dates_bwn_twodates('4/30/2019','5/9/2019'),fourmod,'exp3']

exp_list = [exp1,exp2,exp3]
days_list = [2019-03-06, 2019-03-09, 2019-03-10,2019-04-07,2019-04-15]
for j in days_list:
    for k in explist:
        if k[0].isin([j]).any() == True:
            print(j, k[2])
        elif k[0].isin([j]).any() == False:
            print(j,"normal")
```

My present output

```
.
.
2019-03-09  normal
2019-03-09  normal
2019-03-10  normal
2019-03-10  normal
2019-03-10  normal
2019-04-07  exp1
2019-04-07  normal
2019-04-07  normal
2019-04-15  normal
2019-04-15  exp2    
2019-04-15  normal
..
```

My expected output

```
2019-03-09  normal
2019-03-10  normal
2019-04-07  exp1
2019-04-15  exp2    ..
```

Comment: How do you think `if ... == True:` and `if ... == False:` work? What's the `dates_bwn_twodates()` function? Are you not using proper objects to represent the dates?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to identify matches in you exp_list.  With the next() function you can get the first match and use its second parameter to indicate a default value of "normal" when there is no match.

Here's an example of how this could be done:

```
exp1 = ('2019-03-22','2019-04-09','exp1')
exp2 = ('2019-04-10','2019-04-19','exp2')
exp3 = ('2019-04-30','2019-05-09','exp3')

exp_list  = [exp1,exp2,exp3]
days_list = ["2019-03-06", "2019-03-09", "2019-03-10","2019-04-07","2019-04-15"]
for j in days_list:
    expr = next((expr for lo,hi,expr in exp_list if j>=lo and j<=hi),"normal")
    print(j,expr)
```

Note that, if you are using strings, the format of your dates must all be YYYY-MM-DD so that the  comparisons will work properly.  If you use actual Date() values, this is not an issue.